# Pyqt5 QAbstractTableModel dataChanged not updating data

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I am trying to update my QTableView after I receive a notice via pydispatcher of a change in the system. I did create the following functions

```
def rowCount(self, parent=None):
    return len(self.m_list)

def columnCount(self, parent=None):
    return len(self.table_def)

def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
    if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        return self.table_def[col]['Header']
    return QVariant()

def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    if not index.isValid():
        return None
    if index.row() >= len(self.m_list) or index.row() < 0:
        return None

    row = index.row()
    col = index.column()

    print("Called for (%s, %s, %s)" % (row, col, role))
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        return self.table_def[index.column()]['Function'](index.row())
    elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
        batch = (index.row() // 100) % 2
        if batch == 0:
            return QApplication.palette().base()

        return QApplication.palette().alternateBase()
    else:
        return None

def flags(self, index):
    if not index.isValid():
        return None
    return Qt.ItemIsEnabled

def update_model(self, data):
    print('update_model')
    index_1 = self.index(0, 0)
    index_2 = self.index(0, 1)
    self.dataChanged.emit(index_1, index_2, [Qt.DisplayRole])
```

The line `self.dataChanged.emit(index_1, index_2, [Qt.DisplayRole])` does not seems to do anything; i.e. `data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole)` is not called.

If I click on the table, then `data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole)` is called and the table update.

The fix that I have right now is to call beginResetModel() and endResetModel(). That works, but it is not how it should work.

Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: This should work. Try `QtCore.Qt.EditRole` but that shouldn't make a difference. My guess is that there is a bug elsewhere which swallows the update. Try to connect to the signal and print when it's emitted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it just by calling **self.headerDataChanged.emit** instead. So, to do that, once you change something in the table, call the following:

```
self.headerDataChanged.emit(Qt.Horizontal, idx1, idx2)
```

where self._data is your data within the class. idx1 and idx2 are the first and last indexes of changed data, respectively. `Qt.Horizontal` is an example and it could be vertical depending on your table content.